# Node Request Piping set response header

Tags: node.js, request

I am streaming a file upload in node.js and then piping the response back to the client.  I want to set the content-type on the final response, but can't seem to find in the docs.

```
req.pipe(proxyReq).pipe(res);
```

I've tried

```
res.header('content-type', 'text/plain');
```

But the response gets set back to 'application/json'.

Is there good docs to how this is working and how I can set the response header?

Answer (score 1):

the piped response is where the headers are being grabbed from so simply setting:

```
proxyReq.response = res;
```

fixed it.

Comment: Can you clarify? Or give the full code snippet? I am unclear on the order of the operations

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still experiencing this problem. This is how I fixed it:

```
  const x = _request.pipe(proxyReq);
  x.end();

  x.on("response",(res)=>{
    const routedResp = res.pipe(response);
    routedResp.setHeader("content-type","application/json");
  })
```

*_request* and *response* being the middleware passed parameters.
*request* being 'http.request'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044948/388951) to a related question.

```
req.pipe(proxyReq).on('response', function(res) {
  res.header('content-type', 'text/plain');
}).pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.headers['someHeader'] = 'someValue'` before the pipe request to set the header for the pipe request and `res.headers['someHeader'] = 'someValue'` to pass header to the response.