# No headers in proxied request with Express

Tags: node.js, express

My express server has to proxy requests to another server listening on a unix socket file.

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
   let opts = {
      socketPath: 'file.sock',
      path: req.url,
      method: req.method,
      headers: req.headers
   };
   const proxyReq = http.request(opts, (proxyRes) => {
      proxyRes.pipe(res, {
          end: true
      });
   });
   req.pipe(proxyReq, { end: true });
});
```

The problem is that the response headers are not being passed on from the proxied server to the Express response. The client gets the Express server headers instead.

My questions:

1. How do I correctly pipe all of `proxyRes` into `res`?
2. Is there a way I can avoid having the proxied server response parsed and pipe the raw socket data back to the client? The same applies to the request. I'd like making the proxying as transparent as possible while keeping Express as the top level server.

Comment: you might find this inspiring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042725/edit-response-headers-before-piping

Comment: Thanks, very inspiring indeed. I still wonder how to do a raw request using `http.request` instead of `request`

Comment: @ojosilva Umm, that's what the answer there actually tells you. You seem to be reading it in reverse as they say **don't** use `request`, but use `http.request` instead. Other answers there also give alternate approaches either way.

Comment: But they all seem to require that headers be injected into the response. Isn't there a way to just proxy the raw socket stream without any parsing of headers involved? My question is the opposite of the examples given, where the OP is trying to get a hold of headers.