# How to handle a C# ByteArrayContent in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple C# web api service that returns a pdf document as bytearraycontent in the response of an IHttpActionResult. I can easily handle this as a blob on the client (js in browser) and set it as a the src of an iframe. Everything displays correctly.

Due to some changes in requirements, I'm now implementing a simple appserver in nodejs using express; this will serve as  a proxy server. From my client, I'm able to make the call to this express server, which in turn calls my C# service. I get 200 http OK status code, but seem to not be able to the handle pdf byte array in node. I tried Buffer methods, readstreams etc... Nothing worked.

Can you guys throw some light on this? Below is the code:-

```
httpRequester.get(`${constants.serviceTarget}/api/DocGen/Download/Id/true`, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(body)) // this is always false
                const stream = streamifier.createReadStream(response.body)
                console.log("Created stream")
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=document.pdf");
                res.writeHead(response.statusCode)
                stream.pipe(res)                
                console.log("Sent stream to response")
                console.log("***********************************")
            }
        })
```

Comment: Also, the code here runs fine - no errors, but the pdf returned back to the client has no content.

Comment: Why is the callback declared as async, when there is no await call inside it?

Comment: Thank you @tutiplain. I was trying some async methods as part of my research before. Accidentally left it there. Cleared it now

Comment: So does it work now? If you console.log the value of body and response.body, what do you get?

Comment: Yes. Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was doing too much here. Since I'm using nodejs request module to make the GET call, all I need to then do is pipe the response to the client; like below:-

```
httpRequester.get(`${constants.serviceTarget}/api/Pandadoc/DownloadDocument/${opportunityId}/true`, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }).pipe(res)
```

I got the idea from: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2910

Comment: This works only because you don't need the additional headers. Here you can find solutions with adding the extra headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042725/edit-response-headers-before-piping

Comment: Thank you for the link @inf3rno!  For now, yes I'm good without altering the incoming headers but will keep the additional insight handy.